# In a Sinatra App on Heroku, Session Is Not Shared Across Dynos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, sinatra

Which makes sense. But what are some preferred work arounds for this issue?

Comment: Search for "Sinatra File-Based Sessions" and "Sinatra Database-Based Sessions". Here's an old temp-file based session solution: http://paterni.org/wiki/Sinatra_temp_file_sessions

Comment: This might work, if you don't have a lot of session data: http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/classes/Rack/Session/Cookie.html

Comment: @matt You should post that as an answer.

Comment: There is no file writing on heroku. So no file sessions.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In my comment, I suggested using [rack cookie based sessions](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/classes/Rack/Session/Cookie.html), but looking into it, the Sinatra sessions *are* Rack cookie sessions anyway.

Looking further, I [found this in the Sinatra docs](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Using%20Sessions):

> To improve security, the session data in the cookie is signed with a session secret. A random secret is generate for you by Sinatra. However, since this secret will change with every start of your application, you might want to set the secret yourself, so all your application instances share it:
>
> > `set :session_secret, 'super secret'`

So it seems each Heroku dyno is generating a different key, and so can't read each others session cookies, and you need to specify a key so each dyno uses the same one.

Rather than add a secret key to your source code, you're probably better setting an [environment variable](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#cli_usage):

```
$ heroku config:add SESSION_KEY=a_longish_secret_key
```

Then in your sinatra app:

```
enable :sessions
set :session_secret, ENV['SESSION_KEY']
```

Comment: Looks good. Have not had a chance to confirm yet. Based on 3 up votes, I am accepting the answer.

Comment: since environment variables aren't always available in development, I suggest `set :session_secret, ENV['SESSION_SECRET'] || 'something'`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a memcached session for performance or security. Have not tried it but looked easy. 5MB free on heroku.

Answer (score 0):

```
# In your app.rb file just add following - 
enable :sessions
set :session_secret, "some_random_value"
```