# Sinatra session members "disappearing"

Tags: ruby, session, heroku, sinatra

I've successfully troubleshooted an issue with session members not being available even though they were set and would like to know why it's happening. My situation can be described as:

1. Sinatra app using `:session`.
2. Using oAuth to authorise users and in the process setting a `:ret_url` session member so that the app knows where to come back to after auth.
3. Server is unicorn on Cedar stack (Heroku)

This works perfectly whilst running locally but the `:ret_url` session member was completely disappearing from the session on Heroku. I found that if I removed this code it fixed the problem:

```
  before do
    cache_control :public, :must_revalidate, :max_age => 60
  end
```

Question 1: I'm guessing that my cookie was being cached without the `:ret_url` value and that's why it was breaking?

Question 2: I was setting the session member as shown in the route condition code below, is this the wrong place to do it?

```
  # redirect users to login if necessary
  set(:auth) do |access_token|      
    condition do

      if request.request_method == 'GET'
        session[:ret_url] = request.path_info 
      end

      redirect '/' unless user_logged_in?
    end
  end
```

*I'd like to use cacheing and still have my cookie be valid.*

Comment: Did you set a session secret key? set :session_secret, 'super secret'

Comment: I am having the issue where session members exist when I run my Sinatra app locally, but which vanish when running on Heroku.  I've tried using oAuth and now Koala to interact with Facebook and both end up exhibiting the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

A chap by the name of Ari Brown (waves at Ari), who is not a member here but deserves the credit for this answer, pointed me at the right solution, which is, as per [the Sinatra FAQ](http://www.sinatrarb.com/faq.html#sessions), to not use `enable :sessions` but to `use Rack::Session::Cookie` as per

```
use Rack::Session::Cookie, :key => 'rack.session',
                           :domain => 'foo.com',
                           :path => '/',
                           :expire_after => 2592000, # In seconds
                           :secret => 'change_me'
```

I've added this into my `config.ru` and all is well.

I also noticed over in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115136/in-a-sinatra-app-on-heroku-session-is-not-shared-across-dynos) the alternative suggestion to `set :session_secret, 'change_me'` and, indeed, to do this via an environment variable, namely:

```
$ heroku config:add SESSION_KEY=a_longish_secret_key
```

then in your app

```
enable :sessions
set :session_secret, ENV['SESSION_KEY'] || 'change_me'
```

Obviously you can use the environment variable strategy with the `Rack::Session::Cookie` approach too. That's the way I went as it offers more flexibility in configuration.

The reason these work is that the cache controller middleware is farming requests out to multiple server instances and without setting a session secret it's just making one up per server, and thus breaking the sessions.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to see what is going on without knowing all details, but there is a simple rule that you are most probably violating: do not use http caching on actions that are supposed to do something (other than just show page). When http caching is on, you browser does not even try to re-load the page and renders it from browser cache.

Cookies are not cached anywhere, the only thing cache_control does is setting CacheControl http response value

In your case the best thing you can do is to add list of routes that have no-action pages to your before block:

```
before '/my/static/page' do
  cache_control :public, :must_revalidate, :max_age => 60
end
```

Most probably you will have very limited set of routes where you can benefit from http caching

Comment: Related: you should not use `:public` if your response includes or otherwise depends on anything user- or session-specific. I usually set up a middleware specifically for resources I want to cache -- one that strips out all incoming cookies and session data to prevent me from referencing something by accident.